# Taking an open subset of a subspace and recovering an open subset of the larger space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be locally compact Hausdorff and $Y \subseteq X$ a closed subspace. The open subsets of $Y$ are precisely the open subsets of $X$ intersect $Y$. But given an open subset $U$ of $Y$, can we write $U = V \cap Y$ for some open subset $V$ of $X$? This seems plausible in "nice enough" spaces, but I can't think of a systematic way to build $V$ from $U$.

The problematic points are those in $U \cap \textrm{bd } Y$. For each $x \in U \cap \textrm{bd } Y$, I was thinking of adding some open neighborhood of $x$ to $U$. But to preserve $U = V \cap Y$, these open neighborhoods cannot intersect $Y \backslash U$. Since $X$ is regular, maybe I can take an open neighborhood of $x$ that does not intersect $\overline{Y \backslash U}$? I am not sure if this works as I am ignoring a lot of the fine details.

Edit: I realized my construction doesn't work in the case that $x \in \overline{Y \backslash U}$.

Comment: Your question is rather odd: by definition, an open subset of $Y$ is a subset of the form $V \cap Y$ , so the hypotheses of your problem include the inclusion. I suspect you are asking is whether there is some process for recovering a suitable $V$ from a given open $U \subseteq Y$ in some "constructive" way. Perhaps you could rethink and revise your question.

Comment: @RobArthan I agree, my question is rather trivial. I just was just overthinking the definition of the subspace topology. For some reason, I thought the subspace topology was merely generated by sets of the form $V \cap Y$ for open $V$, not the collection of sets of this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $(X, \tau_X)$, an arbitrary topological space, and consider a subset $Y \subseteq X$.

We define the "subset topology" on $Y$ to be $\tau_Y = \{Y \cap V | V \in \tau_X\}$.

In other words, the open subsets of $Y$ are exactly those that can be written $Y \cap V$ for some open subset $V \subseteq X$.

So by definition, if we have any open subset $U \subseteq Y$, it is always possible to write $U = Y \cap V$ for some open $V$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The question is: "But given an open subset $U$ of $Y$, can we write $U = V \cap Y$ for some open subset $V$ of $X$?" The answer is: yes, by the definition of the subset topology.

Comment: Thanks, I was overthinking this way too much. I literally wrote the answer to my own question in the second line.